# Sharing URL On Facebook using Addthis

Tags: facebook, addthis

we have a news website and using AddThis plugin to share news on Facebook ,
sometimes when we try to share news on Facebook it doesn't detect the page info (title ,desc , image ) and when we put the same URL on Facebook debugger every thing running correctly and 
page info detected , and when return to the web site and use the same URL we can share it normally .

the web site created using asp.net 4.0 + SQL server 2008 + iis 6 and the website behind a firewall

thanks

===
( Update )..

after trying Facebook debugger i got this error :

"Error Parsing URL: Error parsing input URL, no data was scraped. "

and after trying it after 2 days i can share the link without use the debugger .
then i try the debugger and it's working with out error (same link )

Answer (score 0):

Facebook uses a lot of caching especially for shared links. Once a user has shared a link, Facebook will cache the title, test and images it scraped from that URL.

When you pass a URL though the Facebook Debugger, Facebook will clear it's cache on that URL and use the new data. So the actual act of passing the URL though the debugger is what is causing the differences.

Usually you'll only pass the URL though the debugger again when something has changed on that URL and you want it Facebook to know about it.

Comment: === ( Update )..

after trying Facebook debugger i got this error :

"Error Parsing URL: Error parsing input URL, no data was scraped. "

and after trying it after 2 days i can share the link without use the debugger . then i try the debugger and it's working with out error (same link )

Answer (score 0):

The Facebook URL debugger also serves to re-scrape the page, so if you're having trouble with sharing the wrong data to Facebook run it through there to refresh their caches.